# Basic Rails question - How to create a new entry in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

```
Product: name, shop_id (foreign key), brand_id (foreign key), price
Shop:    name
Brand:   name
```

The associations are:

```
Product: belongs_to :shop
         belongs_to :brand
Shop:    has_many   :products
         has_many   :brands,   :through => :products
Brand:   has_many   :products
         has_many   :shops,    :through => :products
```

**Question 1**

Are these associations makes sense ? Would you add other associations ?

**Question 2**

I would like to pre-populate the database in `db/seeds.db`.

To add a `Shop` or a `Brand` I do:

```
Shop.create(:name => shop_name)
Brand.create(:name => brand_name)
```

What would be the most appropriate way to add a `Product` ? Do I really need to insert manually the `shop_id` and the `brand_id` values ? If the shop and the brand of the newly created product are not exist yet, will they be added automatically to the database ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general idea with the associations you made is to do this:

```
shop = Shop.create(:name => shop_name)
shop.brands << Brand.create(:name => brand_name)
```

Or the other way around. You don't have to manually create the join model if you don't want to.

**Edit: Here's a demonstration regarding your comment below.**

Set up the migrations.

```
$ ./script/rails g model Shop name:string
$ ./script/rails g model Brand name:string
$ ./script/rails g model Product brand_id:integer shop_id:integer
$ rm test/fixtures/*

$ rake db:migrate; rake db:test:prepare
```

The models.

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :shops, :through => :products
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :brands, :through => :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

The test. Notice that no line of code explicitly creates a product.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ShopTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def test_brand_assignment_to_shop
    assert_equal 0, Product.count

    shop = Shop.create(:name => "Foo Shop")
    brand = Brand.create(:name => "Foo Brand")
    shop.brands << brand

    assert_equal 1, Product.count
    assert_equal shop.id, Product.first.shop_id
    assert_equal brand.id, Product.first.brand_id
  end
end



$ ruby -I./test test/unit/shop_test.rb 
Loaded suite test/unit/shop_test
Started
.
Finished in 0.029778 seconds.

1 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Comment: Did you try it? Inserting products is exactly what that code will do.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I don't understand why `shop.brands << brand` adds a product. Could you elaborate ? How would you define the `name` and the `price` of this product ?

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating the product model, according to that the associations are right.

You can also use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) which allows you to save attributes on associated records through the parent.

For seed, I think yes you have insert manually shop_id and brand_id. These can be done as follows:

```
@shop = Shop.create(:name => shop_name)
@brand = Brand.create(:name => brand_name)

Product.create(:shop_id => @shop.id , :brand_id => @brand.id)
```

Keep in mind that first the parent should be created then the child so, while inserting the data first create the shop and brand and then create product

Hope, this might solve your issue

Comment: What are the use-cases when the OP has to insert IDs manually?  As far as I can suggest, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will do the trick.

Comment: Actually the attributes of brand are not passed in the shop so accepts_nested_attributes_for will not work. If you pass the brand data in shop, then through accepts_nested_attributes_for will create a association between the brand and shop